# PHP: Declaration of arguments in function parameters

Tags: php, function, scope, predefined-variables

First of all, I can't recall the name of this process, but it looks something like this:

```
function test($alter = FALSE){
    //do stuff
    return $alter;
}
```

Making $alter = FALSE right in the function declaration

What is that called? How does this work?  What happens in the following circumstances?

$result = test();

$result = test(TRUE);

Comment: You could always test it. If you don't already, you should figure out how to get access to php [on the command line](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php) so you can experiment with things like this.

Comment: I was more curious in what it was called.  Overloading I believe is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: [Overloading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) is something different, but default parameters can be hacked to achieve some of the same effects. In overloading, you define multiple methods with the same name, but with different [signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_signature), and the compiler chooses which one to apply based on what you pass in and expect out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FALSE` is defined as the default value if no other value is passed.

In the case of you examples the results (in order) would be:

```
FALSE
TRUE
```

Comment: +1 See the section 'Default argument values' on [this man page](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Answer (score 1):

FALSE defined in method header is the default value (if nothing is added to parameter while calling) - `test()` otherwise it behaves like a normal parameter.. so if you call `test(TRUE)` value will be TRUE

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to add except: The term that you probably might be remembering is "function overloading" but this isn't a **real** embodiment of this (it's just PHP's "default parameter" is perhaps *similar*)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php calls it "default values for scalar arguments" (see example 3)

Answer (score 1):

```
"<?php
echo"welcome";
function a($b=false){
echo"<br /> b: ".$b;
}


a(true);
a();
a("some text");
a(false);
```

?>
result :
welcome
b: 1
b:
b: some text
b: 
"

it seems that if its false/null/empty it does not print anything..
and what ever you pass to that method string/boolean it does print as long as not null/empty.